# 'Unable to get value of the property 'Id'' error from jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to integrate jqGrid into an ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor view and have hit a snag that has me baffled.  When I attempt to hit the view in debug-mode using IE9, I am getting this Javascript error:

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'id': object is null or undefined.`

Razor:

```
<link href="/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName - Contacts/Providers</legend>
        <table id="clientContacts" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    </fieldset>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#clientContacts").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetClientContactsAndProviders")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['clientContactId', 'Type', 'Who', 'Phone', 'button', 'Comments'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'clientContactId', index: 'clientContactId', hidden: true },
                { name: 'contactType', index: 'Type', width: 190, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'contactName', index: 'Who', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'contactPhone', index: 'Phone', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'newContactButton', index: 'button', width: 50, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'contactComments', index: 'Comments', width: 240, align: 'left'}
            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            width: 780,
            height: '100%'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetClientContactsAndProviders(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var clientId = CookieHelper.GetClientIdCookieValue();
    var client = _clientRepo.GetClient(clientId);
    var contacts = client.Contacts.ToList();
    var model = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = contacts.Count,
            rows = contacts.Select(c =>
                new
                    {
                        clientContactId = c.ClientContactId.ToString(),
                        contactType = c.ContactType.Description,
                        contactName =
                            c.Contact.Person.FirstName + " " + c.Contact.Person.LastName,
                        contactPhone = c.Contact.Person.Phone1 ?? string.Empty,
                        newContactButton = string.Empty,
                        contactComments = c.Comments ?? string.Empty
                    }).ToArray()
        };
    return Json(model);
}
```

I do not get this error in Chrome, and I can't for the life of me figure out what this mythical "id" property is.  Please help!

**Edit (after @Justin Ethier answer):**
Full disclosure, didn't think this mattered, but I'm attempting to pass in four "empty" rows in this situation.  In these cases, `clientContactId` defaults to 0, and I think this may have been part of the problem.  I changed my grid Javascript as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clientContacts").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetClientContactsAndProviders")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['clientContactId', 'Type', 'Who', 'Phone', 'button', 'Comments'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'clientContactId', index: 'clientContactId', hidden: true },
            { name: 'contactType', index: 'Type', width: 190, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'contactName', index: 'Who', width: 200, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'contactPhone', index: 'Phone', width: 100, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'newContactButton', index: 'button', width: 50, align: 'center' },
            { name: 'contactComments', index: 'Comments', width: 240, align: 'left'}
        ],
        rowNum: 20,
        width: 780,
        height: '100%',
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'rows',
            page: 'page',
            total: 'total',
            records: 'records',
            repeatitems: true,
            cell: 'cell',
            id: 'clientContactId',
            userdata: 'userdata',
            subgrid: { root: 'rows', repeatitems: true, cell: 'cell' }
        }            
    });
});
```

Then, and most importantly, when the four rows are "empty" I added this code to build the `rows` object that jqGrid expects:

```
var rowBuilder = new List<object>();
for(var i = 0;i < contacts.Count; i++)
{
    rowBuilder.Add(new
                       {
                           id = i + 1,
                           cell = new
                                      {
                                          clientContactId = contacts[i].ClientContactId.ToString(),
                                          contactType = contacts[i].ContactType.Description,
                                          contactName =
                       contacts[i].Contact.Person.FirstName + " " + contacts[i].Contact.Person.LastName,
                                          contactPhone = contacts[i].Contact.Person.Phone1 ?? string.Empty,
                                          button = string.Empty,
                                          contactComments = contacts[i].Comments ?? string.Empty
                                      }
                       });
}
var model = new
                {
                    total = 1,
                    page = 1,
                    records = contacts.Count,
                    rows = rowBuilder.ToArray()
                };
return Json(model);
```

And now it works!

Comment: Maybe the jqGrid can't see your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jqGrid uses a `jsonReader` for retrieving json data. If one is not explicitly provided, the grid uses the following default one, [according to the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data):

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

I suspect that the `id` you are receiving the error for is the `id` column the default reader is expecting, which is missing from your result set. You should be able to fix this by providing a reader that specifies the correct row ID:

```
jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: "page",
    total: "total",
    records: "records",
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "cell",
    id: "clientContactId",
    userdata: "userdata",
    subgrid: {root:"rows", 
    repeatitems: true, 
    cell:"cell"
    }
},
```

Does that help?

Comment: I think you're right.  I didn't know that it used this `jsonReader`.  Part of my problem right now is that this grid can be prepopulated with four empty rows if no contacts exist for the client yet.  I'm currently creating a dummy result set to test your theory, though.

Comment: Thanks!  This was indeed part of the problem.  See my edits to the original post.  Any further comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GET the cell value in firefox, chrome you have to use...

`Trow.cells[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` will work for all browser while

`Trow.cells[0].innerText` will work only for ie not for firefox and chrome....